# Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below

Tags: ipad, xcode, downgrade

I'm getting the following message when tethering one of my iPads used for testing. Its telling me to *"Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below..."*, but it does not provide the list:

[image]

The image above was cropped to help with presentation, but not text was removed from the image.

What is the list of OSes that Apple recommends I downgrade to? They seems to have forgotten to provide the list.

Related, how does Apple recommend I do it? As far as I know, effectively downgrades can't be performed.

---

Oddly, iTunes can work with the everything just fine (my OS X version and iOS version). So it seems Apple is more than happy to accommodate the non-latest OS X and iOS when it comes to selling me stuff...

Answer (score 1):

The latest version is iOS 8.3. It would seem it's time to upgrade.